# How to use `isin` in Polars DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars

I have a polars DataFrame:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({'A': ['red', 'blue', 'green', np.nan, 'orange']})
my_list = ['red','orange']
```

I want to know which colors are present in `my_list`.

In pandas, I would do something like:

```
df.A.isin(my_list)
```

But, I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'A'
```

How to do this in polars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following can be used to create a dataset where column *A* is replaced by a boolean column indicating whether each item was in `my_list`.

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("A").is_in(my_list))
```

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌───────┐
│ A     │
│ ---   │
│ bool  │
╞═══════╡
│ true  │
│ false │
│ false │
│ null  │
│ true  │
└───────┘
```

If instead you'd like to

- *create* a new boolean column, use `pl.Expr.alias` as follows

  ```py
  df.with_columns(pl.col("A").is_in(my_list).alias("B")
  ```
- have the return value be a `pl.Series` (like in @KrisKruse's answer), use `pl.DataFrame.get_column` as follows

  ```
  df.get_column("A").is_in(my_list)
  ```
- *filter* for rows for which the value of *A* is in `my_list`, use `pl.DataFrame.filter` as follows

  ```py
  df.filter(pl.col("A").is_in(my_list))
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Hericks' answer.

```
df.get_column('A').is_in(my_list)
```

Where the output is a series of bools referring to whether or not the item was in my_list